# If a solution to Partition is known to exist, can it be found in polynomial time?

Tags: reductions, np-hard, partitions

In the Partition problem, there is a set of integers, and the goal is to decide whether it can be partitioned into two sets of equal sum. This problem is known to be NP-complete.

Suppose we are given an instance and we know that it admits an equal-sum partition. Can this partition be found in polynomial time (assuming $P\neq NP$)?

Let's call this problem "GuaranteedPartition". On one hand, apparently one can prove that GuaranteedPartition is NP-hard, by reduction from Partition: if we could solve GuaranteedPartition with $n$ numbers in $T(n)$ steps, where $T(n)$ is a polynomial function, then we could give it as input any instance of Partition and stop it after $T(n)$ steps: if it returns an equal-sum partition the answer is "yes", otherwise the answer is "no".

On the other hand, the GuaranteedPartition is apparently in the class [TFNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFNP), whose relation to NP is currently not known.

Which of the above arguments (if any) is correct, and what is known about the GuaranteedPartition problem?

Comment: You should probably be clearer about what you mean by NP-hard. Under the definition "NP-hard under Karp reductions" it should be obvious that GuaranteedPartition cannot be NP-hard (as is explained on the wikipedia page you linked). But indeed, if GuaranteedPartition is in P, so is Partition, as you correctly argue.

Comment: The first argument shows that if P≠NP then GuaranteedPartition cannot be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Suppose we have an algorithm that solves GuaranteedPartition correctly when an equal partition exists, but when an equal partition does not exist, its behavior is undefined (as in the C++ standard https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub ). Then I am not sure the first argument works. I am also unsure if the concept of "undefined behavior" makes sense at all. This is quite confusing.

Comment: We don’t care what the algorithm does. If it doesn’t output a valid partition after the allotted time, we know that no such partition exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the whole misunderstanding comes from an incorrect definition of TFNP. TFNP is for problems like factoring, where there is always a solution. Every integer has a prime factorization, so you don't have to make any restrictions on what inputs are allowed - i.e., every input string of bits represents a number that has a factorization. This is different from a [promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem#Formal_definition), which is more like what you're describing.

Unlike integers and factorizations, there are sets that do not have equal-sum partitions. And if you change the input format to be some strange representation of sets of integers such that every set represented always has a valid partition, then you change the problem entirely. A program that solves this new problem probably couldn't be used to solve the original NP-hard Partition problem.

(GuaranteedPartition is also not a decision problem, so it's not NP-hard either - although a machine that solved GuaranteedPartition could be used to solve anything in NP, as you point out.)

Comment: This clarifies the issue. Thanks!